# Conditional recode in R

Tags: r

I have ten gender variables from `2007-2017` (`gender1`, `gender2`,...,`gender17`).

I want to create an **`overall_gender`** variable equal to the most recent gender record.

Ideally I want to use a loop that says something like: if `gender17 = "N/A"`, use `gender16`, if `gender16 != "N/A"`; and so on.

For example:

```
       ID y1 y2 y3 y4 y5 y6 y7 y8 y9 y10
1 person1  M  M  M  M  M  M  M  M  M  NA
2 person2  M  M  M  M  NA NA NA NA NA NA
3 person3  F  F  F  F  F  F  NA NA NA NA
4 person4  M  M  M  M  F  F  F  NA NA NA
```

Desired output:

```
       ID Gender
1 person1      M
2 person2      M
3 person3      F
4 person4      F
```

Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: The [`coalesce`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/dplyr/versions/0.7.3/topics/coalesce) function from the __`dplyr`__ package is worth a try, provided you mean that `"N/A"` values are actually coded as `NA`

Comment: Could you just look for any presence of M or F? Gender shouldn't change by person right?

Comment: It is possible that gender would could change overtime. Otherwise I would just melt and aggregate gender for each person

Comment: Please provide a small, reproducible example.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this, using `tail` and `is.na` to identify the latest non-NA value

```
#example data
df <- data.frame(Gender1=c("M","F"),Gender2=c("M","M"),
                 Gender3=c(NA,"M"),Gender4=c(NA,NA),stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

df$overall_gender <- apply(df,1,function(x) tail(x[!is.na(x)],1))

df

  Gender1 Gender2 Gender3 Gender4 overall_gender
1       M       M    <NA>      NA              M
2       F       M       M      NA              M
```

Answer (score 0):

With `dplyr` + `tidyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

bind_cols(df, df %>%
  gather(variable, Gender, -ID) %>%
  na.omit() %>%
  arrange(ID, variable) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  slice(n())) %>%
  select(-variable, -ID1)
```

**Result:**

```
       ID y1 y2 y3 y4   y5   y6   y7   y8   y9 y10 Gender
1 person1  M  M  M  M    M    M    M    M    M  NA      M
2 person2  M  M  M  M <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>  NA      M
3 person3  F  F  F  F    F    F <NA> <NA> <NA>  NA      F
4 person4  M  M  M  M    F    F    F <NA> <NA>  NA      F
```

**Data:**

```
df = read.table(text = "       ID y1 y2 y3 y4 y5 y6 y7 y8 y9 y10
                1 person1  M  M  M  M  M  M  M  M  M  NA
                2 person2  M  M  M  M  NA NA NA NA NA NA
                3 person3  F  F  F  F  F  F  NA NA NA NA
                4 person4  M  M  M  M  F  F  F  NA NA NA", header = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a fairly compact solution, assuming that the column names will always have the form `"y*"` with `*` a number:

```
library("dplyr")

# where `dat` is the table in the post:
dat %>% 
  reshape2::melt(id.vars="ID") %>% 
  filter(!is.na(value)) %>% 
  mutate(variable = as.numeric(gsub("y", "", as.character(variable)))) %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  summarize(gender = value[variable==max(variable)])
```

You can use `mutate()` instead of `summarize()` if you want to maintain the information in the long-form dataset (all the info in the original table, except doesn't list the `NA`'s). But if you do that, make sure to pipe the result into `ungroup()` right after!